# How do I assign values to an array using scanf within a for loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, scanf, assign

```
int main (void)
{
   int i = 1; 
   int arrayOfNumbers[4];

   for(i = 1; i >= 4; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter a Number");
      scanf("%d", &arrayOfNumbers[i]);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler compiles the program, however the for loop just doesnt happen. This program is simply a dud. How do I create a loop designed to assign all the values of an array?

Comment: Here the expression is invalid, the condition is not satisfy due to 1>=4 so it can't execute, try this one i<=4. Why don't you are try to assign the value from 0 to 3. In 4th position the value cannot assign properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
for(i = 1; i >= 4; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter a Number");
      scanf("%d", &arrayOfNumbers[i]);
   }
    return 0;
```

to:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter a Number");
      scanf("%d", &arrayOfNumbers[i]);
   }
    return 0;
```

Since 1 is not bigger than 4 it will not go through the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right declaration for `for` loop:

```
for ( init-expression ; cond-expression ; loop-expression )
```

In your code, you set your initial value of `i` as 1 & in `condition-expression` your code fails in the first condition itself where `1` is not greater than `4`.

Your `for` loop declaration should be

```
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
//code to be executed
}
```

Complete code for your program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
   int i = 1; 
   int arrayOfNumbers[4];

   for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter a Number \n");
      scanf("%d", &arrayOfNumbers[i]);
   }
  printf("Your Entered number is.. \n");
  for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
   {
     printf(" %d",arrayOfNumbers[i]);
     printf("\t");
   }
return 0;
}
```

The following code gives us output as,

```
Enter a Number 
1   
Enter a Number 
2
Enter a Number 
3
Enter a Number 
4
Your Entered number is.. 
 1   2   3   4
```